# Error Message: "offset (0) + length (4) exceed the capacity of the array: 2" while fetching data from HBase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

My tomcat based REST API application is not able to process request due to above mentioned error. I am facing an error while trying to retrieve data from HBase. I am using RESTFul webservices as my interface.

I am using CDH 5.3.1 which contains HBase 0.98.6. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?`enter code here`

Error Details:
Error Message: "offset (0) + length (4) exceed the capacity of the array: 2"

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you need to change some schema type specifications?

I got this error, except with `offset (0) + length (4) exceed the capacity of the array: 1`. This was because the value for the column in question was missing, and I assumed the 1 byte indicated null value.

This happened when using spark to hbase connector in Java, and having specified the column type to be "int", e.g.:

{"cf": "fam", "col": "someColumn", "type": "int"}

Changing type to "string" resolved the problem, and missing values displayed as null instead of result in an error.

Comment: you are the best

Answer (score 0):

same issue here. root cause for me is that the data produced/consumed is not through the same API.

I used python rest API to generate test data, which when retrieving is only 7 bytes long and does not meet consumer's requirement (8 bytes)

in your case, your producer produces only 2 bytes long and consumer expects 4 bytes.

you have to adapt at either end.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same error.offset (0) + length (4) exceed the capacity of the array: 3.

Because on HBase,the type is String，but the entity in my class is Integer.So,bytes can't transform.
you must ensure that the types that are put and get from HBase are same.

eg: 
HBase --> productId : s_23476

Entity --> private Integer productId